Unable to exchange authorization code for access token in eBay
I'm integrating eBay's OAuth API into my C# application to generate an access_token by exchanging an authorization_code.
However, I get the following error during the token exchange:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "the provided authorization grant code is invalid or was issued to another client"
}

Current implementation

Generating the Authorization URL
I generate the URL to redirect users to eBay's login page for consent. After the user logs in and grants consent, eBay provides an authorization_code.
Here's how I generate the URL and prompt users to visit it manually:

string authCodeUrl = BuildAuthorizationUrl();
Console.WriteLine($"Please visit this URL to provide consent: {authCodeUrl}");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = authCodeUrl,
    UseShellExecute = true
});


Exchanging the Authorization Code for an Access Token
Once the user manually inputs the authorization_code in the console, I use the following method to exchange it for an access_token:

public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(string authorizationCode)
{
    string tokenUrl = "https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token";
    string clientId = "<Your Client ID>";
    string clientSecret = "<Your Client Secret>";
    string redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080/"; // Must match the redirect URI in eBay app settings

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var authHeader = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeader);

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
            { "code", authorizationCode },
            { "redirect_uri", redirectUri }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenUrl, content);

        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {responseBody}");
            throw new Exception($"Error retrieving the access token. Response: {responseBody}");
        }

        var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenResponse>(responseBody);
        return tokenResponse.access_token;
    }
}

Problem: when I call GetAccessTokenAsync, I consistently get the invalid_grant error.
Expected outcome: a successful response similar to the following:
{
    "access_token": "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#r^1...XzMjRV4xMjg0",
    "expires_in": 7200,
    "refresh_token": "v^1.1#i^1#p^3#r^1...zYjRV4xMjg0",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 47304000,
    "token_type": "User Access Token"
}


You should be using Encoding.UTF8 not Encoding.ASCII. See here

I have solved the error. Actually I am copying the code from URL after giving consent and place it directly. The code in URL  is encoded so first we have to decode it then use then use decoded string.

and thank you @Itallmakescents for pointing.can you tell me one more thing that how i automate the step currently i am opening the url then give consent manually and copt the code from url and paste in console and do further processing.Now i want the all step automate .
